# Requesting "foreign" Api within ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I write a Web Api 2 Project and within one Method (POSTing a new Location), I want to retrieve some Information, the user not provides (Country, City, region).

I found a solution in the Google Maps API:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.91845,1.44315&sensor=true`

This meens, I must only provide the lat and lon coords within this URL.
How can I send this request and process the result within my own API Method?

My method is till now:

```
public string PostNewLocation(string mName, decimal mLat, decimal mLot)
{
    // Here should be the calling and resolving of the Google API
    // string mCity = ...
    // string mCountry = ...

    // Adding new location to database follows here and works fine...
}
```

Comment: Use System.Net.Http.HttpClient.  Sorry I don't have time for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string PostNewLocation(string mName, decimal mLat, decimal mLot)
{
//do a get request to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.91845,1.44315&sensor=true

//deserialize the json response to your own object and do stuff with it

var response = googleAPIService.Get(mLat, mLot);

//do something with the response

}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but where can I find and how can I implement `googleAPIService` ?

Comment: That is a task for yourself to implement. Break it down into small baby steps. So 1) Get the Json response from the url. 2) Deserialize into your own object.

Comment: That was my introducing question: How can I send the request and get the Response from an URL...